# Custom decoration for QListView

Tags: c++, qt, styles, qlistview

I'm writing a GUI that runs on both Linux and Windows, and makes extensive use of the `QListView` class. I'd like to keep the look of the GUI consistent for users on both systems.

Out of the box, Qt uses different decorations for expandable/collapsible item icons on those systems. Is there any way, perhaps using a delegate, to replace the decoration with a custom set of icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Qt 5.* you can use the platform independent **Fusion** style. It looks pretty much the same on different platforms. Just add in your main.cpp :

```
qApp->setStyle("fusion");
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for since I'd prefer to use a custom icon, but definitely worth a +1 for its simplicity.